# How to make a PUT commit request to the Github Rest API with Arduino WiFiClientSecure

Tags: github-api, arduino-esp32

I have a Doit ESP32 Devkit V1 and use the Arduino IDE to program it. I want to store data at a GitHub repository by sending a PUT request to the GitHub rest api using the WiFiClientSecure library.

Following [this tutorial to create a secure connection to a server with ESP32](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-https-requests/#esp32-https-requests-wificlientsecure) I downloaded the CA certificate, created a token with read / write permission for my repository and now trying to make a PUT request to the GitHub rest api.

I also read [this specification of the api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents).

I get the following response:

```
20:10:17.817 -> Starting connection to server...
20:10:19.623 -> Connected to server!
20:10:19.623 -> ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request
20:10:19.623 -> Content-length: 90
20:10:19.623 -> Cache-Control: no-cache
20:10:19.623 -> Connection: close
20:10:19.623 -> Content-Type: text/html
20:10:19.623 -> 
20:10:19.623 -> <html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
20:10:19.670 -> Your browser sent an invalid request.
20:10:19.670 -> </body></html>
20:10:19.670 -> ⸮Request complete!
```

Following the code of my attempt:

```
void sendPUTRequest(float fLuxValue, String sTimestamp)
{
    client.setCACert(GITHUB_ROOT_CA);
    Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");

    client.setTimeout(10000);
  
    if (client.connect(GITHUB_ADDRESS, 443))
    {
    
        String sRequestType = "PUT https://api.github.com/repos/" + sGitHubUser + "/" + sGitHubRepo + "/contents/Measurement" + String(ulGitHubCommitCounter) + ".json";
        String sHTTPType = "HTTP/1.1";
        String sAccept = "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json";
        String sHostInfo = "Host: api.github.com";
        String sUserAgent = "User-Agent: ESP32LighSensorApp/1.0 (Doit ESP32 DevKit V1)";
        String sAuthToken = "Authorization: Bearer " + sGithubToken;
        String sAPIVersion = "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28";
        String sContentType = "Content-Type: application/json";
     
        String sContent = "{\"timestamp\":\"" + sTimestamp + "\",\"value\":\"" + String(fLuxValue) + "\"}";

        String sRequestBody = "{\"message\": \"Sensor data " + String(ulGitHubCommitCounter) + "\",\"content\":\"Qg==\",\"branch\":\"main\"}";

        int iContentLength = sRequestBody.length();
    
        Serial.println("Connected to server!");

        // Set the necessary headers
        client.println(sRequestType);
        client.println(sHTTPType);
        client.println(sAccept);
        client.println(sHostInfo);
        client.println(sUserAgent + " " + sAuthToken);
        client.println(sAPIVersion);
        client.println(sContentType);
        client.println("Content-Length: " + String(iContentLength));
        client.println();
  
        // Set the request body
        client.println(sRequestBody);
  
        // Send the request
        client.println();
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Connection failed!");
    }

    // Read and process the server response
    while (client.available() || client.connected()) {
        // Read and process the response data
        char c = client.read();
        // Process the received character
        Serial.print(c);
    }
  
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Request complete!");

    ulGitHubCommitCounter++;
}
```

I'm new to this stuff (sending requests to apis) and can't really find any example at the web that's not using curl or something else.

Can someone explain to me, what I'm doing wrong and how I have to do it?

I tried putting all the headers into json-format, since some of the headers look like they could be json attributes.

I expected the request to be successful and creating a file at a GitHub repository.

Have a nice day!